# R for functions and making values

Tags: r, for-loop

I am currently learning R as a nubee.
I am trying to make some values using 'for' function.
I have looked through many questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the answer.

I guess this is a question that does not need any reproducible data so I will not put inside the `EXTRACTION`dataframe.
So What I would like to have as an output is

```
CC2<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(2)])
CC2<-sub(".", "", CC2)
CC3<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(3)])
CC3<-sub(".", "", CC3)
CC4<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(4)])
CC4<-sub(".", "", CC4)
CC5<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(5)])
CC5<-sub(".", "", CC5)
CC6<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(6)])
CC6<-sub(".", "", CC6)
CC7<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(7)])
CC7<-sub(".", "", CC7)
CC8<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(8)])
CC8<-sub(".", "", CC8)
CC9<-colnames(EXTRACTION[c(9)])
CC9<-sub(".", "", CC9)
```

literally this code. However, It is too long to write all of these codes down, so I decided to use for function.

```
for (i in 2:9){function(x){sub(".","",colnames(EXTRACTION[c(i)]))}}
```

but after this, I could not add up the 'CC's and 'i' as the output code I would want. The reason is when I add up as
`"CC"+"i"`,it stands as characters so Rstudio would not understand the forloop I made.

What could be the solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: Also -- why are you trying to create a large number of global variables? Why not instead create a single vector `CC` and use something like `CC[i]` rather than `CCi`?

Comment: I did not quite get your question. So you mean ```CC[i]``` can vary for each i? I am not familiar with vectors, so I just decided to make a whole lot of variables instead.

Comment: The entire point of vectors is that they give you a good way of dealing with multiple pieces of data without needing separate names for each datum. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the question that you asked, but [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is one of the most important principles of programming. Whenever you find yourself writing essentially the same line of code again and again, think of a different approach.

In this case you are trying to make a series of global variables, each of which is implicitly indexed by an integer. Why not make that indexing more explicit? Have a single global variable, say `CC` where `CC[i]` holds the same value as `CCi`. Something like the following should work:

```
CC <- sub("[.]", "", colnames(EXTRACTION))
```

Then `CC[2], ..., CC[9]` correspond to `CC2, ..., CC9`

If you *only* want the names for columns 2:9 then you could use

```
CC <- sub("[.]", "", colnames(EXTRACTION[2:9]))
```

though in that case it would be `CC[1]` which corresponds to your `CC2`.

Note: in the above I assumed that your intention was to replace a literal dot in the names by the empty string rather than dropping the first character, which is what happens when you use the regular expression `"."` by itself, since dots are wildcards that can stand for any character. Putting it in a character class (via []) suppressed that wildcard behavior. You could also use `"\\."` (which is in some ways more obscure -- regular expressions are not the most intuitive things).

Comment: Thanks John, but the thing is when I make a single vector CC, I cannot apply the column name numbers, So for example, for ```CC2```, I take it from ```colnames(EXTRACTION[c(2)])``` and for CC3, ```colnames(EXTRACTION[c(3)])```and so on. I guess so from this part, I thought it was better to make a large number of variables instead.

Comment: @ThomasLee I'm not sure what you are saying. The entire point of using a vector is so that you don't need to put the column numbers as part of the variable name. Whether or not you know it, you are in effect creating an inconvenient vector. Just make it explicit and learn to use `CC[i]` instead one of a large number of different variables.

Comment: Oh....I did not catch that ```CC <- sub("[.]", "", colnames(EXTRACTION[2:9]))``` can be a vector and differ for each [i]. Thanks. I will use the single vector case only. Also, the ```"."``` was actually to erase the first character. As my column names were ```X2020.11.05```and I wanted to drop the X.  Thank you very much John, I appreciate your answers and I will study hard.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `sprintf` function:

```
sprintf("CC%i<-sub(\".\",\"\",colnames(EXTRACTION[c(%i)]))", i, i)
```

To better understand `%i` or any other string format, from the documentation `?sprintf`

> The string fmt contains normal characters, which are passed through to the output string, and also conversion specifications which operate on the arguments provided through .... The allowed conversion specifications start with a % and end with one of the letters in the set aAdifeEgGosxX%. These letters denote the following types:
>
> d, i, o, x, X
> Integer value, o being octal, x and X being hexadecimal (using the same case for a-f as the code). Numeric variables with exactly integer values will be coerced to integer. Formats d and i can also be used for logical variables, which will be converted to 0, 1 or NA.

Comment: Wow thanks, it works! So the important thing is to add % in front of the i. I am sorry but it does not tell in '?sprintf', so can you please explain the \".\",\"\" part? and why 'i' is written twice in the back? Sorry for asking easy questions too much.

Comment: No, `%i` has nothing to do with your loop index `i`. `%i` means that the substituted value will be an **i**nteger -- this is in the documentation `?sprintf`. For each substitution you need to supply a value. Since there are two substitutions here, `i` is passed twice. The backslash escapes the quotes so they do not interfere with the string. This means you want a literal quote, otherwise how would the parser be able to tell where the string starts and ends since there are multiple quotes

Comment: This will accomplish what you need, which is printing this string with the substituted values. However, this is likely not the best way to accomplish what you're actually trying to do. If you add more information about your problem, you'd get a better answer.